# Impossible to add MikTex gpg key

Tags: gnupg, miktex, keyserver

I'm trying to install MikTex on Ubuntu 18.04 following the instructions in the [website](https://miktex.org/download).

The first command,

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys D6BC243565B2087BC3F897C9277A7293F59E4889
```

gives the error

> gpg: keyserver receive failed: Invalid argument

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know the root cause, but following the instructions [here](https://linuxer.eu/apt-key-gpg-keyserver-receive-failed/) I was able to get the keys.

These download and install the gpg key:

```
wget -q \
  "https://keyserver.ubuntu.com/pks/lookup?op=get&search=0xD6BC243565B2087BC3F897C9277A7293F59E4889" \
  -O- | gpg --dearmor \
          > miktex-D6BC243565B2087BC3F897C9277A7293F59E4889.gpg
sudo mv miktex-D6BC243565B2087BC3F897C9277A7293F59E4889.gpg \
        /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/
```

You should then be able to continue with the next steps (`sudo apt update` and so on).